# Find 2 elements in an array that give a target result in a simple equation

Tags: excel, vba, loops, equation

In electronics I need a certain resistance, however there are limited standard values on the market. If I make a combination of two resistors in parallel, I could get a very close result to the target. The question is which 2 resistors could give the best result.

So far i have these elements:

> 1. Excel column of 86 standard values from 0.25 to 1000000 in A2:A87 cells
> 2. Target resistance that I enter in cell C3
> 3. R1 and R2 - variables that can get 86 values from A2 to A87 cells
> 4. equation giving the parallel resistance: Rtarget=R1*R2/(R1+R2)

I am a VBA ignorant and find this task as a good opportunity to learn more about VBA operations. Here I started with the variables, but I do not know how to proceed. Your help would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub ResCom()

Dim Rstd As Double 
Dim Rt As Double, R1 As Double, R2 As Double

Rstd = Range("a2:a87").Value

.
.
.

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If only 68 values - why cells 2 to 87 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a tool that can easily be reused.

First enter the resistance values in **A2** through **A87**. Then run:

```
Sub tablemaker()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, K As Long

    K = 2
    For i = 2 To 87
        For j = i To 87
            Cells(K, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(K, 3) = Cells(j, 1)
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    Range("D2:D" & K - 1).Formula = "=B2*C2/(C2+B2)"
End Sub
```

This will create a resistance table in **B2** through **D3742**.  The table lists  combination pairs and the associated resistance of each pair.

*(permutations are not need since the pair 4,2 is really the same as 2,4)*

Then enter the target value in cell **E2**.  In **E3** enter the ***array formula***:

```
=MATCH(MIN(ABS(D2:D3742-E2)),ABS(D2:D3742-E2),0)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

This gives the row in the table with the closest match.Finally in **E4** enter:

```
=INDEX(B2:B3741,$E3)
```

and copy this to **F4**

[image]

To re-run this, just change the target in **E2**

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, use this to continue

```
Option Explicit

Sub ResCom()

    Dim Rstd As Double
    Dim Rt As Double, R1 As Double, R2 As Double

    Rstd = Range("a2:a87").Value

    ' step thru upper triangle of R1/R2 values
    ' (lower triangle gives same results)
    Dim r1Row As Long, r2Row As Long
    For r1Row = LBound(Rstd) To UBound(Rstd)
        For r2Row = r1Row To UBound(Rstd)
            ' here is where you solve for  Rtarget=R1*R2/(R1+R2)
            ' R1 = Rstd(r1Row)
        Next r2Row
    Next r1Row


End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't allow for 2 resistors of same size ... 2nd loop should surely be all resistor values ?

Comment: @KneeColas, why that? 2nd loop starts where 1st does so it does allow for 2 resistor of the same size

Comment: Correct my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub ResCom()
    Dim Rt as Double, R1 as Double, R2 as Double

    Rt = Range("C3").Value

    For i = 2 to 87
       R1 = Range("A" & i).Value
       if R1 < Rt Then
          For j = 2 to 87
             R2 = Range("A" & j).Value
             if Round(Rt,2) = Round((R1*R2/(R1+R2)),2) then
                ' Success you have found a Resistance Combination that matches
             End If
          Next j
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

...